# jQuery Validator accepting invalid dates

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

Why does the jQuery Validator accept this as a valid date?

01/123/1

If you enter that date it passes validation.  How can I ensure the user is entering a valid date?  I do not want to use a datepicker.

Link to validator: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/date

Comment: The demo on the page show that it is not a valid date

Comment: I was using firefox and it comes up as valid.  I just checked Chrome and it says invalid...What browser are you testing in?

Comment: I used chrome to check, post your source

Comment: Why does my source matter? The code on the jQuery site doesn't work in Firefox.

Comment: file a bug report with jquery

Comment: It's not your code and this is not a bug reporting site.  This is a site to help you fix _your_ code.

Comment: Read the original post, I asked for another method of how to enter a valid date, without using datepicker.  Instead of being a comment pirate you could have responded with a constructive answer.  Instead I found the answer myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the built-in date functionality doesn't work in Firefox, here is an extension method that works in all browsers.  This also checks to make sure the date is valid, 99/99/9999 will not work.

```
    $.validator.addMethod(
        "mmddyyyy",
        function(value, element) {
            var match = /^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/.exec(value),
            isDate = function (m, d, y) {
                return m > 0 && m < 13 && y > 0 && y < 32768 && d > 0 && d <= (new Date(y, m, 0)).getDate();
            };
            return match && isDate(match[1], match[2], match[3]);
        },
        "Please enter a date in the format mm/dd/yyyy."
    );



    $('#Form1').validate({
        rules: {
            birthDate: { required: true, mmddyyyy: true }
        }
    });

});
```